# Twig templating within <script> tag

Tags: templating, javascript

I think I might be missing something here but it seems twig tags aren't parsed within  tags? Is there any way they can be, e.g.:

```
<script>
var homepageStandfirstAnchors = [<% for anchor in homepage.homepageStandfirstAnchors %>[{{ anchor.text }},{{ anchor.section.handle }},{{ anchor.anchorLink }}],<% endfor %>];
</script>
```

doesn't work as expected.

Comment: My bad - should have been {% not <%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be due to the angle brackets. Try:

```
<script>
    var homepageStandfirstAnchors = [{% for anchor in homepage.homepageStandfirstAnchors %}[{{ anchor.text }},{{ anchor.section.handle }},{{ anchor.anchorLink }}],{% endfor %}];
</script>
```

Comment: DUH whoops. I'll delete this question but thanks!